# Get child object its children objects into List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to add all objects that are way way nested inside my parent object to a List. The child objects are 100s of it which are way nested in multiple gameObjects. How do I add them to my list through script?

```
public List<GameObject> allObjs = new List<GameObject>();
public GameObject parent;

public void GetAllProducts () {
         foreach (Transform  g in parent.transform)
        {
            allObjs.Add(g.gameObject); //Gets only child but not its children
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you define "objects"? Up to which base-class do you want to consider a member? Do you just want to list the Properties, or also fields? What about objects internally created by some function? Your question is completely unclear. Please provide more context of what you want to achieve.

Comment: How do you even define "nested"? What about members like lists or dictionaries and their containing elements?

Comment: You will probably need to create a recursive function.

Comment: You should add your code changes not modify the original. You started with GetComponentsInChildren<GameObject>, it was the right method with the wrong type. Now you have parent.transform which only get the first depth children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GameObject is not a component so you cannot use with GetComponentXXXXX

You could use the Transform since it is the one component found on every game object:

```
public List<GameObject> allObjs = new List<GameObject>();
public GameObject parent;

public void GetAllProducts () 
{
    foreach (Transform tr in parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
    {
        allObjs.Add(tr.gameObject); 
    }
}
```

Add true to GetComponentsInChildren to also find inactive objects:

```
 parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true)
```

Comment: the loop is still quite redundant .. simply do `GameObject[] allObjs = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true);` or if it is still needed to be a list rather use `allObjs = new List(parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true));`

Comment: But the method returns an array of Transform and they need to be stored in a list of GameObject. He could just get away with a Transform [] though.

Comment: you are absolutely right, overlooked this detail :)